# iphoneOS backgrounding sockets

Tags: ios, sockets, background

I've a simple TCP client which connects to a simple TCP server sending the word "ping" every 5 seconds. I read these "pings" using the command read from the standard C socket library.

```
int numberOfBytes = read(m_clientSocketFileDescriptor,buffer,255);
if (numberOfBytes < 0) { 
    error("reading from socket");
}
```

I have set the WIFI usage, background sound and background voip values in my application plist file.
I declare my socket to be backgrounded as following :

```
 - (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
 {
   if (m_clientSocketFileDescriptor) {
         CFStreamCreatePairWithSocket(kCFAllocatorDefault, m_clientSocketFileDescriptor, &m_tcpReadStream, nil);
         if (m_tcpReadStream != NULL) {
         CFReadStreamSetProperty(m_tcpReadStream, kCFStreamNetworkServiceType, kCFStreamNetworkServiceTypeVoIP);
         }
    }
  }
```

This works perfectly when i press the home button. My pings are received from the server, and when i wake up my application, all the messages have been received.
My problem is when i use the power button to lock the iPhone screen. The socket is actually closed. My server is receiving a SIGPIPE error, and when i wake up the phone, the read() function says : "Socket is not connecting".

I think it's pretty dumb to have a background socket if this is getting down when the user locks the screen (by default, this happens afer between 1 or 5 minutes), so maybe i'm doing things in a wrong way.

Does anyone managed to overcome this problem ?
Tested on iOS 5.0 with an iphone 3GS & iphone 4.

Comment: Did you try `setKeepAliveTimeout:handler:` as suggested by @DarkDust?

Perhaps there's some preparation to do in `applicationWillResignActive:`?

Answer (score 1):

You might need to use [-[UIApplication setKeepAliveTimeout:handler:]](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/setKeepAliveTimeout%3ahandler%3a). I guess that if you don't have this handler the OS can assume that your app won't be able to handle any responses to the socket anyway and closes it. See also [Apple's Tips for Developing a VoIP app](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW12).